# How to test branches of a function called by another function in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have a function that gets the npm package's version. That function is broken into three this way:

```
**version.ts**

import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const getPathToPackageJson = (): string =>
  path.resolve(__dirname, "../", "../", "../", "../", "package.json");

const getPackageJson = (path: string): object =>
  fs.existsSync(path)
    ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: "utf8" }))
    : undefined;

const getPackageJsonVersion = (): string =>
  getPackageJson(getPathToPackageJson())["version"] || undefined;

export const versionUtils = {
  getPackageJsonVersion,
  getPathToPackageJson,
  getPackageJson
};
```

I want to test the undefined branch. Right now my test looks like this:

```
**version.spec.ts**

import { versionUtils } from "./version.utils";

jest.mock("../../../../package.json", () => {
  return {
    version: "1.0.0"
  };
});

describe("getting the package.json version", () => {
  test("return 1.0.0", () => {
    expect(versionUtils.getPackageJsonVersion()).toEqual("1.0.0");
  });
});
```

So, that part works, but I'm missing the undefined branch to have 100% coverage. The question here isn't really if I actually need that, but whether I want it. And I do.

I've tried several ways with jest.fn(), jest.spyOn(), jest.mock() with jest.clearAllMocks(), but to no avail. Anyone out there knows how to go about testing the undefined return?

Answer (score 0):

This worked, in the end:

file

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const getPathToPackageJson = (): string =>
  path.resolve(__dirname, "../", "../", "../", "../", "package.json");

const getPackageJson = (p: string): object =>
  fs.existsSync(p)
    ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(p, { encoding: "utf8" }))
    : undefined;

const getPackageJsonVersion = (): string => {
  const p = getPathToPackageJson();
  const packageJson = getPackageJson(p);
  if (packageJson) return packageJson["version"];
  else return undefined;
};

export const versionUtils = {
  getPackageJsonVersion
};
```

test

```
import { versionUtils } from "./version.utils";
import fs from "fs";

jest.mock("fs");

describe("getting the package.json version", () => {
  test("return undefined if file not found", () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, "existsSync").mockReturnValue(false);
    const version = versionUtils.getPackageJsonVersion();
    expect(version).toBeUndefined();
  });
  test("return 1.0.0", () => {
    const packageJson = '{ "version": "1.0.0" }';
    jest.spyOn(fs, "existsSync").mockReturnValue(true);
    jest.spyOn(fs, "readFileSync").mockReturnValue(packageJson);
    const version = versionUtils.getPackageJsonVersion();
    expect(version).toEqual("1.0.0");
  });
});
```